# How to emit one event after finishing previous one using NgRx?

Tags: redux, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to this technology and I am working on a project where blow's the scenario.

table schema:

## tbl.Product

id 
product name 
brand_id [FK]

## tbl.Brand

id 
BrandName

in this, while submitting I am adding BrandName first and taking the newly added id of brand record and insert full record in product table with brand_id.

```
Submit(){

this.saveBrand.emit(brand);
product.brand_id = brands.id;
this.saveProduct.emit(product);

}
```

for this, I am using NgRx Store.

Brand.effects.ts

```
addBrand$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .pipe(ofType<Add>(BrandActionTypes.Add),
      switchMap(action => this.BrandService.addBrand(action.payload)),
     map((Brand: any) => new AddSuccess(Brand)),
      catchError(err => {
        toastr.error(`Could not add Brand.`);
        console.error(err);
        return of(new AddFail(err));
      })
    );
```

Product.effects.ts

```
addProduct$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .pipe(ofType<Add>(ProductActionTypes.Add),
      switchMap(action => this.ProductService.addProduct(action.payload)),
     map((Product: any) => new AddSuccess(Product)),
      catchError(err => {
        toastr.error(`Could not add Product.`);
        console.error(err);
        return of(new AddFail(err));
      })
    );
```

while executing this both event emitting together (both are not async). so product is not getting brand_id.
i am expecting output like.

```
Submit(){

this.saveBrand.emit(brand); 
product.brand_id = brands.id;
this.saveProduct.emit(product); \\hold until brand get added

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching an action is an async process, that's why the brand id isn't "populated".
To solve your problem you can do a few things:

- your products effects can listen on the `AddSuccess` action
- use one effect to handle both service calls
- make on service call?

A great article about some of the patterns [NgRx: Patterns and Techniques](https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5?source=search_post---------0)

Comment: not working for me.
I am having trouble in chain operations.